# Echo Spot record video using inbuilt camera - Custom skill

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit

I have a requirement to record video using Amazon device.

Currently, I have the Echo spot device and tried to find some way from which I can open the camera and start recording until I give the command to stop, using the custom skill. But didn't get the success.

What I have gone through till now is:

- [Alexa.CameraStreamController Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/device-apis/alexa-camerastreamcontroller.html) By which I can handle the
  camera and
- [Alexa.MediaMetadata Interface](https://developer.amazon.com/de/docs/device-apis/alexa-mediametadata.html) to handle recorded videos.

But couldn't find anything useful. Can I use an inbuilt camera to record and then upload to `s3` bucket?

I have already developed a skill which is able to start recording on PI device using Amazon Echo device. But this time I need to use an inbuilt camera of Echo spot.

Any help or guidance would be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The video recording feature via the built-in camera is not supported.

Here is the forum discussion link.
https://forums.developer.amazon.com/answers/191435/view.html