# Echo show 5 record video using inbuilt camera

Tags: echo, alexa-skills-kit, amazon-echo-show

Is it possible to record video/acquire photo with Echo Show 5 inbuilt camera?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53377484/echo-spot-record-video-using-inbuilt-camera-custom-skill

Answer (score 2):

> **No**, currently we cannot record via Echo show's inbuilt camera.

Here, the snapshot from [Amazon developer forum](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/191389/echo-spot-record-video-using-inbuilt-camera-custom.html?childToView=191435#answer-191435),
[image: video recording in echo show - accepted answer]

Be sure to watch [Alexa monthly updates](https://build.amazonalexadev.com/preference-center.html) to get the latest features as it's been evolving in our eyesight.

Comment: Are you saying that currently there aren't public APIs to create an application such as Skype on Alexa?

Comment: Yes, as up-to my knowledge and reach there is no provision to do so.